# cakephpでコメント一覧が表示されない

Tags: php, cakephp, dotinstall

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力][image: 画像]

ドットインストールでcakephpを勉強しています。
「コメント一覧を表示する」というものですが、正しく表示されないです・・・
modelに問題があるなのか、それともviewで正しく表示できていないのか・・・
どなたか教えてください。

ドットインストールの動画
http://dotinstall.com/lessons/basic_cakephp/7527
http://dotinstall.com/lessons/basic_cakephp/7528

【Comment.php】

```
<?php

class Comment extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = 'Post';
}

?>
```

【Post.php】

```
<?php

class Post extends AppModel {
    public $hasMany = 'Comment';

    public $validate = array(
        'title' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty',
            'message' => '空です'
        ),
        'body' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty'
        )
    );
}

?>
```

【view.ctp】

```
<h2><?php echo h($post['Post']['title']); ?></h2>

<p><?php echo h($post['Post']['body']); ?></p>

<h2>Comments<h2/>
<ul>
<?php foreach ($post['Comment'] as $comment): ?>
<li><?php echo h($comment['body']) ?> by <?php echo h($comment['commenter']); ?></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

コメントを取得するSQLで結果が空なことから、DBに入っているデータに問題がある気がします。

質問のスクリーンショットで表示されているのは`id=1`の記事とお見受けします。

そのシリーズの[「#26 Commentsテーブルを用意しよう」という回](http://dotinstall.com/lessons/basic_cakephp/7526)で`comments`テーブルにデータを投入する際、「DBの中身を見るとidが7～10なので、じゃあ適当に7としましょう」といった流れで`post_id`を`7`としたSQLを書いていますが、これは表示する記事の`id`と一致させる必要があります。

動画の通り`post_id=7`のデータを投入してしまったために、コメントが取得できなかったのでは・・・と思いましたがいかがでしょうか？

#### 参考

[アソシエーション: モデル同士を繋ぐ — CakePHP Cookbook 2.x ドキュメント](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/ja/models/associations-linking-models-together.html)

Answer (score 0):

スクリーンショットにあるQuery Nr.2の行数(Num. rows)が0になっていますので、commentsテーブルにデータが無いですね。

Comment: テーブル画像のデータを追加しました！これではないのでしょうか？

Comment: @DaikiYamada unaristさんの書かれている通りpost_idが間違っています。

Comment: unaristさんのおっしゃるとおりでした。アソシエーションの構造をきちんと理解しておりませんでした。。。ありがとうございます